# Compare column contents and highlight matches or near-matches

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to highlight all the cells in column A and column C that are identical or near-identical (with just one or two letters' difference.)

Also, I need to highlight cells if there are similar words in a sentence.

[image: A picture of what I'm looking for]

Comment: I like this question. However, what formulas have you tried so far? Is VBA a solution too?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't feel like a task that Excel is particularly well-suited for. It has some basic text-manipulation functions, but no "string metric" functions. You could perhaps implement something like [bchatham's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697939/935614).

Other software has better string-analysis tools. *Mathematica* is the one I would use for this, but of course it's not free.

Comment: There is a `Share` button beneath every post. There you get a direct link :)